# Как сделать long shadow icons на css?

Tags: css

Возможно ли сделать качественные long shadow icons на чистом css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если поддерживаются градиенты и множественные фоны, то можно всё.
http://habrahabr.ru/company/paysto/blog/251933/
http://a.singlediv.com/

Впрочем, всё можно и без них, только нужные элементы придётся в разметку положить.

А ещё, насколько чистый css, который в фон помещает заинлайненную в нём svg-картинку?

Comment: Ух ты, сугои. Я даж не знал что такие вещи можно на css3 вытворять. Аригато ( ･ั﹏･ั)